# Finding bits from audio file?

Tags: signal, sampling

I am assigned to do lab that is allowed to ask other people for hint.

I am given an uncompressed PCM WAV file that has signal like following image:

[image: Here is an iamge]

And this is question:

- determine the sequence of bits that were transmitted. Hint: the remote control transmitter contains a sticker inside with a number 50325 printed on it. The number is transmitted somewhere in the signal given, in binary.

Does that transmitted bits mean 3 bit representation which I can obtain after sampling and quantization? (as explained in the bottom of following webpage -
 https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece110/su2017/content/courseNotes/files/?samplingAndQuantization)

So somewhere in signal has 1100010010010101 (50321 in binary) as 3-bit representation? so there is a sequence of bits that contains ... 110 001 001 001 010 1.... ?

Comment: In addition to Andy's excellent answer you'll need to know (or work out for yourself) the coding scheme - RZ, NRZ, Manchester, bi-phase mark, or whatever other system is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am given an uncompressed PCM WAV file

Basically it's a wav file and a wav file has this format: -

[image]

So, try and decode it based on that and note that the 50321 byte size might be implied by the BitsPerSample definition.

Comment: I haven't a clue but I got the impression that the WAV file oscilloscope trace gave the data stream and *that's* what he wants to decode - not the file itself.

Answer (score 2):

> So somewhere in signal has 1100010010010101 (50321 in binary) as 3-bit representation?

It is a leap to assume that each digit is coded as three bits. It could be a number of base encoding schemes.

Start with expanding your view of each packet so that you can see the individual signal transitions (a small time scale on the X axis). This will afford you the opportunity to test the possible coding scheme for the signal as Brian pointed out.

Once you have the coding scheme worked out, you can reduce the packet to its binary one and zero form. From there, you can determine the base conversions, etc. to find the 50321 part of the message in order to confirm that you can report the entire binary message accurately.

And in all of this, don't lose sight of the fact that most lab projects relate directly to recent lecture material. If you just studied NRZ coding for example, I would place this on the top of the list for the possible coding scheme. If, on the other hand, you are studying cryptography...

Comment: And remember also that the symbol length may or may not be an integer number of audio samples. I would start by thresholding the audio file to convert into a vector of 0s and 1s, then figure out the symbol rate (you can do that by zooming in on the audio), and what does the modulation look like. One quick check is (Having chopped out a data burst and thresholded it), what is the average value, 0.5 would for example suggest a DC balanced coding scheme like Manchester. An FFT of one of those bursts should hint at the symbol rate.... Looks like a fun course.